# Как отобразить не английский символ в onKey?

Tags: java, android

Собственно простой код. Я ставлю слушатель клавиатуры, получаю символ с помощью `getUnicodeChar` все хорошо пока я ввожу англиские буквы, когда ввожу русские или другие не английские, получаю вопросики кракозяблы, как их правильно то отобразить?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        char unicodeChar = (char)keyEvent.getUnicodeChar();
        testStr = String.valueOf(unicodeChar);
        L.i("testStr="+testStr);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Это смотря как и куда вы их выводите. Возможно там просто Юникод не понимают.

Comment: Я в логи вывожу L.i("testStr="+testStr ) это Log.i("Tag","testStr="+testStr ) Ну потом в другое место но пока хоть так

Comment: Подробнее можете описать ситуацию, где именно перегружаете onKey, тестируемое устройство и тп.

Comment: Я перегружаю onKey в классе реализующем TextureView , обработчик ну на него и ставлю this.setOnKeyListener(this) 12 андроид  эмулятор, но я думаю на всех то же самое будет, по моему там даже русский был в настройках.

Comment: А смотрите результат потом как? Поставьте breakpoint на `L.i(...)` и посмотрите в отладчике что там в переменной `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю почему, но всё что за пределами ASCII клавиатура (по крайней мере AOSP) посылает не символами, а строками.
Получить можно так:

```java
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN) {
            testStr = keyEvent.getCharacters();
        } else {
            char unicodeChar = (char)keyEvent.getUnicodeChar();
            testStr = String.valueOf(unicodeChar);
        }
        L.i("testStr="+testStr);
        return false;
    }
```